# How does the homogenization of a curve using a given line work?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, curves

I am given a curve 
$$C_1:2x^2 +3y^2 =5$$
 and a line
 $$L_1: 3x-4y=5$$ 
and I needed to find curve  joining the origin and the points of intersection of $C_1$ and $L_1$ so I was told to "homogenize" the line with the curve . They basically said that the required  curve would be
$$ 2x^2 +3y^2 -5\left(\frac{3x-4y}{5}\right)^2=0$$
What is this ? And how does this give required curve??

Comment: What are the properties of wanted curve?

Comment: I've been told this is applicable to all curves

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A homogeneous equation, ie, an equation with all terms of same degree, will always represent a set of straight lines passing through the origin.  With this fact in mind, consider the following example:

[image]

I am given a curve of the form $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dy+ex+f=0$ and the line $px+qy=r$ which intersects it at points $A$ and $B$. I need to find the joint equation of the lines $OA$ and $OB$.

To achieve this, I homogenize the equation of the curve by multiplying any term of less than second degree with a factor that doesn't change anything except the degree, ie , unity. Since for any point on the given line, $\dfrac{px+qy}{r}=1,$ I homogenize the curve in this manner:
$$ax^2+by^2+cxy+dy\left(\frac{px+qy}{r}\right)+ex\left(\frac{px+qy}{r}\right)+f\left(\frac{px+qy}{r}\right)^2=0\tag{i}$$
To justify that (i) is, in fact, the joint equation of $OA$ and $OB$, I give two reasons:

1. This is a homogeneous equation, so it is for sure a pair of straight lines through the origin.
2. It passes through the points $A$ and $B$ as they are the points of intersection of the given curve and line, so both the relations $\dfrac{px+qy}{r}=1$ and $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dy+ex+f=0$ are satisfied.

With a similar argument we can say that this 'trick' of homogenization can be applied to any curve of any degree but I think a rigorous proof would require knowledge of projective geometry,scale invariance of homogeneous curves etc.

Comment: “Always” is a bit strong, I think. The equation $x^2+y^2=0$, for example, only has a single real point as its solution set.

Comment: @amd: does the trivial case of the degree being zero also fall under the exception? Great answer though, najayaz.