# How does Homogenization of second degree equation to get equation of pair of straight lines work?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

Consider this figure:

[image]

Here the curve $AB$ is given by $s$,
$$s = ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0 \tag1$$

If equation of line $AB$ is $L$, then, 
$$L = lx + my + n = 0 \tag2$$

To find the equation of pair of straight lines $OA$ and $OB$, we use the method of homogenization of second degree equation i.e., from $(1)$,

$$s = ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2gx(1) + 2fy(1) + c(1)^2 = 0 \tag3$$

From $(2)$,
$$\frac{lx + my}{-n} = 1 \tag4$$

Now substituting $(4)$ in $(3)$,

$$ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2gx\left(\frac{lx + my}{-n}\right) + 2fy\left(\frac{lx + my}{-n}\right) + c\left(\frac{lx + my}{-n}\right)^2 = 0 \tag5$$

This way we can homogenize the equation. Homogenizing equation $(1)$ gives us the equation of pair of straight lines $OB$ and $OA$.

My question is how does equation $(5)$ represent the equation of pair of straight lines?

I know that the pair of straight lines passing through the origin are homogenized equation. But how does equation $(5)$ represent that?

---

Is it like:

The equation

- satisfies the point of intersection $A$ and $B$
- is homogeneous i.e. it must be a pair of straight lines passing through the origin

Due to the above reasons we can conclude that the equation is of the pair of straight lines $OA$ and $OB$. Is it?

These were the same reasons as provided in another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176274/how-does-the-homogenization-of-a-curve-using-a-given-line-work).

---

After checking that post, another question struck my mind. ***Isn't the equation of the curve and the pair of straight line the same as we only substitute equation $(4)$ instead of  $1$ ? If yes, how can this be the case?***

Comment: I would plug in $$y=-\frac{x+n}{m}$$ into the equation $$ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2yx+2fy+c=0$$

Comment: $(1)$ is not the same as $(5)$. Note that $(4)$ holds only for the points on the line $AB$.

Comment: So when we substitute $(4)$ in it, we form an equation such that the points must lie on $AB$ which is different from $(1)$. Is it? I think it is not yet clear. Could you please write an elaborate answer for the last question?

Comment: Consider a point $X(x_0,y_0)$ on $(1)$ satisfying $X\not=A$ and $X\not=B$. Since $X$ is not on the line $AB$, we see that $\frac{lx_0+my_0}{-n}$ is not equal to $1$, which implies that $X$ is not on $(5)$. So, $(1)$ is not the same as $(5)$.

Comment: @mathlove So is it like we are reducing the possible $(x,y)$ solutions. $(1)$ had a larger solution set $(x,y)$. But know as we use $(4)$ in it, the solution set is such that it should also satisfy equation $(4)$. Is it?

Comment: According to my understanding, when we add equation $(4)$ to equation $(1)$, what we are doing is that we are confining the solution set to point $(x,y)$ such that it lies on $(4)$. Now as the the equation became homogeneous, it must be that of a pair of straight lines passing through origin. Moreover, as we use equation $(4)$ in it, $A$ and $B$ must satisfy both equation $(5)$ and $(4)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Are you saying that all the points on $(4)$ satisfy $(5)$?

Comment: No, the points that satisfy $(5)$ must satisfy $(4)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100525/discussion-between-kaushik-and-mathlove).

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Considering

$$
a x^2+b x y + c y^2 = (c_1 x+ c_2 y)(c_3 x + c_4 y)
$$

identifying coefficients we get

$$
\cases{
a=c_1 c_3\\
b = c_1c_4+c_2c_3\\
c=c_2c_4
}
$$

now solving for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ we have

$$
\cases{
c_1 = \frac{b c_4\pm|c_4|\sqrt{b²-4ac}}{2c_4^2}\\
c_2 = \frac{c}{c_4}\\
c_3 = \frac{b c_4\pm|c_4|\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2c}
}
$$

so the condition for a pair of lines is

$$
b^2-4 a c \ge 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since in Eq. (5), the sum of powers of $x$ and $y$ is 2, so it is a homogenous equation of degree 2, notice there is no constant added in it. A homogeneous quadratic may represent just point, pair of real straight lines passing through origin or nothing.
$$ \mbox{A point:}~~~x^2+y^2=0 \implies x=0, y=0$$
$$\mbox{A pair of stright lines:} ~~~ax^2+y^2+3xy=0 \implies y=m x, m_1,m_2=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
$${\mbox nothing :} ~~~x^2+y^2+xy=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation will only be the same if
$$\frac{lx + my}{-n} = 1$$
Which is only true if the point $$(x,y)$$ lies on the line.
Since we are substituting ith in the curve and for the point of intersection of the curve and the line, $$\frac{lx + my}{-n} = 1$$ and the equation of curve
$$s = ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$$ is also satisfied at that point, we are getting the pair of lines passing through the points and the origin.

Answer (score -1):

Doing so we get
$$ax^2+b\left(-\frac{lx+n}{m}\right)^2+2hx\left(-\frac{lx+n}{m}\right)+2x\left(-\frac{lx+n}{m}\right)+2f\left(-\frac{lx+n}{m}\right)+c=0$$
This equation can be solved for $x$.

Comment: But how is this the equation of pair of straight lines $OA$ and $OB$?

Comment: $OA$ or $OB$ has the equation $y=m_1x$ or $y=m_2x$

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Could you please explain the following line first: **'Isn't the equation of the curve and the pair of straight line the same as we only substitute equation $(4)$ instead of $1$ ? If yes, how can this be the case?'**

Comment: Or maybe I didn't understand what you're trying to say. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc So it doesn't represent the equation of pair of straight lines passing through origin, right? It is also not homogenized because of $-\frac{2xn}{m}$ and other terms similar to that. Isn't?

Comment: @Kaushik: Note that the equation in this answer is different from $(5)$. This answer set $y=-\frac{lx+n}{m}$, which is not what you did.