# When does a homogeneous equation represent a set of straight lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, curves, homogeneous-equation

Recently I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176274/how-does-the-homogenization-of-a-curve-using-a-given-line-work) question, where the top voted answer claimed that all homogeneous equation represent a set of straiight lines passing through origin. I was wondering if this was true generally, and if so, how can we  prove this?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the constant term of a homogeneous equation?

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee I know that the constant term of homogeneous equation is 0 thus implying the curves pass through origin. But why does it have to represent a set of **straight lines**? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is a point on the curve then $(\lambda x,\lambda y)$ is also a point on the curve for any real $\lambda$. So for each point (other than the origin) on the curve, you are getting the line through that point and origin also on the curve.

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee Got it! Many thanks:)